# Checking if user authorized in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, orchardcms

I'm writing module for Orchard CMS, and I need show all parts of my Content Type only if user is authorized. Can I do it in View of my module (.cshtml)?

Something about this:

```
if(<statement_about_authorization>)
   @T("part_1"): @Model.part_1<br />
else
   @T("part_2"): @Model.part_2<br />
```

Or maybe with javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never messed with Orchard, but in MVC with asp.net forms authentication, it would look like this:

```
if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    @T("part_1"): @Model.part_1<br />
else
    @T("part_2"): @Model.part_2<br />
```

From a bit of googling, it looks like this should work for Orchard too.

Answer (score 9):

The normal User.Identity.IsAuthenticated will work, but Orchard has a nice way of authorizing your users based on defined permissions too...

```
@if(Authorizer.Authorize(Permissions.PermissionName){

}
```

You can read more about defining permissions here: [Orchard Permissions](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-permissions)

And an example from the blogs module on how to define your own permissions: [Blog Permissions Example](http://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/95f0539354b2#src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Blogs/Permissions.cs)